# replaceWith doesn't work as expected in replacing attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery

replaceWith doesn't work in replacing attr?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js">value</a>
```

```js
$('.js').attr('href').replaceWith('#');
```

I want to replace the href value with #, is this a correct way?

Comment: `replaceWith` is used to change around DOM elements, not replace values in a string. Use `attr()` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
$('.js').attr('href','#')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr()` to get/set attribute values:

```
 $('.js').attr('href','#')
```